# Node and CPU architecture

Tags: node.js, npm, cpu-architecture

I have a node app that is going to run on a small touch screen device that has an ARM CPU. The app itself is pretty simple. I reads data from `syslog` and sends an ipc message to another process if it finds a log entry with some specific data.

My concern is whether or not there will be any issues with installing the npm dependencies on a build machine which is running on a different architecture and then copying it onto the ARM device. The build machine is likely to be a 64 bit Mac or Linux box.

The app seems to work fine when I run `npm install` on my mac and then copy the resulting `node_modules` folder onto the ARM device. However, I had written electron apps for this same ARM device that required us to use [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) with a target architecture of

```
--platform=linux --arch=armv7l
```

for it to run. Simply installing the `node_modules` on a mac then copying them over did not work in that case.

So what is the difference? Is it just the use of electron itself that requires the platform specific build or is it something else I might run into with this new app I'm writing?

Comment: It depends on the dependencies. Do any of them do anything platform-specific, use native binaries etc.?

Comment: if all your dependencies are pure javascript and not platform specific it will probably work. If your dependencies are platform specific or require some native components (for instance built by node-gyp on install) it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find platform specific file by executing:

```sh
find node_modules -name "*.node" |xargs file
```

Comment: Thank you. It does find `node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64` which is associated with the `mocha` unit test library for some reason. I would have though the `node-ipc` module would have platform specific stuff in it but I guess not. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯